# Filtering a PivotTable by specific date

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am looking for a method of automatically filtering a pivot table by a date.

Background - We arrange training for clients with complex healthcare needs and certificates have a certain length of validity (e.g. 12,24 or 36 months). After that time has elapsed, the training is due again.

`\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
Client   & Learner   & Date of Course & Course Name         & Validity & Date Due   \\
Client 1 & Tom Clark & 12/05/2020     & Healthcare Training & 12       & 12/05/2021 \\
Client 1 & Sarah Kay & 12/05/2020     & Moving and Handling & 12       & 12/05/2021 \\
etc      &           &                &                     &          &            \\
etc      &           &                &                     &          &            \\
         &           &                &                     &          &            \\
         &           &                &                     &          &

\end{tabular}
\end{table}`

Sorry I had trouble adding the table in above for example.

How can I create a pivot table which then filters by client and then shows which training needs to be renewed?

See screenshot I was thinking of layout wise.

Any help appreciated or even a better way of displaying this information.

David[image]

[image]

[image]

The above shows the PivotTable field list.

Comment: All Dates in UK format

Comment: Please show a sample of the data that underlies pivot table. Specifically, what is the logic to determine *which training needs to be renewed*?

Comment: Added Field List, let me know if anything else is needed

Comment: The table shot I have added above shows the date of the training and the date due is determined by EDATE(Original Training Date, Validity). This gives me the date which training is due, if that date is in the past, I would ideally like it to display which courses/learners are due for renewal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider creating a new field in data that compares your calculated *Date Due* to today:

```
=[@Due Date] < TODAY()
```

Then, add this new field as a filter in PivotTable, selecting `TRUE` in this boolean field which signifies all dates in the past.

Comment: That is excellent! Thank you. That resolved it. I added a Slicer in to the pivot table for the boolean field and this works a treat.

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help! In fact, I almost recommended a Slicer and even edited it out before posting to avoid confusion.